# is it possible to match these 4 modes of value assignation in regex?

Tags: regex

in many languages there can be many possibilities to assing a string to a variable:

```
var = "some 'quoted' string"
var = 'some "quoted" string'
var = `some 'quoted "quoted" string`
var = somestring
```

Of course in this last variant the space is not possible and end of string is marked by some special character like ; space or > in html.

But my question regards possibility to match all these 4 situations with one regex. The worse situation is with these quotes where first character must be searched at the end of a string and with exception of escaping it.

Comment: Never seen a language that used backticks for string literals...

Comment: Sqlite uses it for table and column names, so it is possible to use single and double quotes in them. Also ruby or python (I don't quite remember) uses concept of custom string beginning and ending character.

Answer (score 2):

```
var = (?:([`'"])(?:(?!\1).)*\1|[^\s;>]*$)
```

works for your examples. If you also want to handle escaped quotes, then try

```
var = (?:([`'"])(?:(?!\1)(?:\\.|.))*\1|[^\s;>]*$)
```

As a verbose regex:

```
var\s*=\s*
(?:      # match either:...
 ([`'"]) # one of the quote characters, then...
 (?:     # match the following any number of times:
  (?!\1) # first assert that the next character isn't the quote we matched earlier
  (?:    # if so, then match either
   \\.   # an escaped character
   |     # or
   .     # an unescaped character
  )
 )*      # repeat as often as needed
 \1      # then match the opening quote character again
 |       # ...or...
 [^\s;>]* #match any suite of characters except whitespace, ; or > up to...
 $       # the end of the line/string
)
```

Comment: Doesn't allow you to escape the quote sign though.

Comment: There's no need to exclude the quotes in that last part; if you get to that point, you know the value isn't quoted.  What you *should* exclude is whitespace.  Also, the OP said there might be a sentinel like `>` or `;` marking the end of a non-quoted value, but I think that would be a case-by-case thing: `[^\s>]*`, `[^\s;]*`.

Comment: @Alan Moore: Good point. I have now included both delimiters in my revised answer; of course the OP can change them to whatever he/she needs.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to use an alternation and describe each format separately:

```
var = ("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|`[^`]*`|[^;\s>]*)
```

And if you want to allow that each delimiter may be used when escaped, add that case as follows:

```
var = ("([^\\"]|\\")*"|'([^\\']|\\')*'|`([^\\`]|\\`)*`|[^;\s>]*)
```

And if you want to allow other characters (or even any character) to be escaped, replace the corresponding escape sequence with a character class containing the characters `\\[…]` or use `\\.` for any character.